# Holomorphic maps preserve Hausdorff dimension.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

In a paper I read there is the following claim:

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a non-constant entire transcendental function(essential singularity at infinity) and $A\subset \mathbb{C}$ a set in the complex plane. Then $f^{-1}(A)$, $A$ and $f(A)$ have the same Hausdorff dimension.

I know that bi-Lipschitz maps preserve Hausdorff dimension but I dont see why entire maps in the complex plane should too. Perhaps because entire maps are locally bi-Lipschitz away from critical points. But do locally bi-Lipschitz maps preserve the dimension?

Can someone prove this or provide a reference for a proof?

Comment: You have the local Hausdorff dimension ...

Comment: What is the local Hausdorff dimension?

Comment: For any $A$ and $x\in A$, the local Hausdorff dimension is defined by $\dim_{locH}(A,x)=\inf\{\dim_H (U\cap A)\mid x\in U\text{ open}\}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\dim_H B_\varepsilon(x)\cap A$ (because $A\subset B\Rightarrow\dim_HA\leq\dim_HB$).  Since $\mathbb{C}$ is separable, $\dim_H(-)=\sup_x\dim_{locH}(-,x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly as you said. Since $f$ is locally bi-Lipschitz, then if $A_n=A\cap \tilde{D}(0,n)$, where $\tilde{D}(0,n)$ is the closed disk of radius $n$, then $\dim_H(f(A_n))=\dim_H(f^{-1}(A_n))=\dim_H(A_n)$, $\forall \ n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Now use that in general, $\dim_H(\cup_{n\geq 1} B_n)= \sup_{n\geq 1} \dim_H(B_n)$.